# A clarification needed to solve drop down meny over riding the banner or header in CSS

Tags: css

I have customized one banner and one drop down menu. On mouse over the menu drop down menu appears. If I scroll this menu is not going below the banner and it is over writing banner.

[image: My css design]

My menu css3 code

```
    #menu ul {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444444, #111111) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
style.css (line 305)
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

the header or banner css:
#the_header {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #000000 0%, #45484D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your the header or banner css try inserting following code fragment.

```
max-height:30px;
```

this should work.